# Is there any reason to use __DIR__ in the file inclution code?

Tags: php, path

Is there any reason to use `require_once( __DIR__.'/../../foo.php');` instead of `require_once('/../../foo.php')`? In some third party code I see using `__DIR__` prefix in specifying paths. However `.` is in `include_path` in using or not use using `__DIR__` are functionally equivalent. Is there any reason to use `__DIR__`?

Comment: `'/../../foo.php'` is an absolute path from __filesystem root__.... as such, you can't go up (`..`) any level from the root because it's already the top, so it would be an invalid path

Comment: @MarkBaker. It's not. It depends on `include_path` config.

Comment: It's not?!? I'm afraid you're wrong.... as per your `require_once('/../../foo.php')`. A `/` as the first character of a filepath makes it __absolute__ from the filesystem root.... `'./../../foo.php' ` would be a relative path (using the include path to search), where the first character of the path is a `.` rather than a `/`

Comment: Create two file and try it on PHP. You are right regarding the OS meaning of `/` and `.`. But PHP consider the current path the root if `.` is first place in `include_path`.

Comment: @MarkBaker Or perhaps the first absolute path has the highest priority over `include_path`. I'm not sure.

Comment: No.... if the filepath includes a `/` as the first character, PHP treats it as an absolute filepath, and doesn't use the include_path at all..... if the filepath doesn't have a `/` as the first character, then (and only then) will it use the include_path. If the filepath is a relative path (no leading `/`), then the first entry in the include path is typically `.`, so the first check will be relative to the current working directory

Comment: But using \_\_DIR\_\_ forces an absolute path, so the include path isn't used at all.... it does have the benefits of working from the script filepath, so eliminating any confusions of the current working directory and the directory where the file is stored, and it eliminates the overhead of having to search through the include_path entries for the file

Comment: @MarkBaker So at least you mean using `require_once('./../../foo.php')` (with beginning dot) and `require_once(__DIR__.'/../../foo.php')` are always equivalent?

Comment: Not quite always equivalent.... because `require_once('./../../foo.php')` will work from the include path (probably starting with the current working directory), whereas `require_once(__DIR__.'/../../foo.php')` will work from the directory where the file is stored (which may or may not be the current working directory)

Answer (score 4):

`___DIR___` is used because third party code can't control if you have `.` in your `include_path` or not. `___DIR___` always references to the directory of the current file (see [Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)).

Comment: It's really unlikely that `.` is not in `include_path`, but yet possible.